# real time backup if file changed?

Tags: linux, backup, suse, real-time

Are there any linux/unix console applications similar to [Yadis](http://www.codessentials.com/products/yadisbackup.html) that would allow me to:

- be set up from the **console**
- backup **multiple** directories
- backup / sync in **real time** after the files (text files) are changed

**Update 1:**

I write shell scripts, ruby scripts, aliases etc etc to make my work easier. I want to have backup of these files. The solution I am looking for will copy these files after any change was made to them to a subdirectory of my dropbox directory and that's it. Backup is done and available from anywhere. Always fresh and ready and I don't have to think about it.

I know I can run cron few times a day but I thought there must be a solution for what I am looking for available on linux. I am not so linux experienced so I asked here.

Comment: I've always wanted to know what the deal is *vis-à-vis* what happens if I'm rsyncing or whatever the case may be and I'm actively using the system too... but I've always been too shy to ask. So thanks for asking for me!

Comment: @Gilles: In study for that bounty I've been playing with `incron` and have had it making instant backups of a few files of mine lately. It's pretty slick actually, but there are some gotchas, and overcoming those could go different directions. Should the emphasis here be on "real time"/"instant" action or on behaving predictably even though it adds delay to effectively de-bounce file operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably hack this together using `inotify` and more specifically `incron` to get notifications of file system events and trigger a backup.

Meanwhile, in order to find a more specific solution you might try to better define your problem.

- If your problem is backup, it might be good to use a tool that is made to create snapshots of file systems, either through `rsnap` or a snapshoting file system like `xfs` or using any file system with `lvm`.
- If your problem is sycronizing, perhaps you should look into distributed and/or netowrk file systems.

**Edit**: In light of your update, I think you are making this way to complicated. Just make a folder in your dropbox for scripts. Then in your bashrc files do something like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Dropbox/bin
source ~/Dropbox/bashrc
```

Whatever scripts you have can be run right from the dropbox folder in your home directory, and any aliases and such you want synced can go in a file inside Dropbox that gets sourced by your shell.

If other people besides you need access to the scripts, you could symlink them from your Dropbox to somewhere like /usr/local/bin.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @Radek: Updated my answer. If that's all you're trying to do you can make the whole thing really easy ... just leave the stuff in Dropbox!

Comment: I will try to do it the other way. I will symlink the files to Dropbox.

Comment: Your answer helps with my core issue but doesn't answer the `topic` question. Seems to me that that others are interested too....

Comment: That may be, but the "topic" question was theoretical because it did not really apply to your practical problem. If other people have a more specific practical problems I'm sure we can come up with answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep two replicas of a directory tree on two different filesystems, then [ChironFS](http://code.google.com/p/chironfs/) might be the solution.  It's a [FUSE](http://fuse.sf.net)-based filesystem, that replicates any changes to its "virtual" filesystem to two other "real" filesystems.

Installation and usage instructions are available here: http://www.furquim.org/chironfs/howto.html